# In triple boot how to find the swap area of kali and ubuntu individually

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, swap

I have Win10,kali,ubuntu as triple boot and now I have deleted the partition of kali, but I can't identify the swap area of kali. There are two swap areas one for kali and another for ubuntu as I deleted kali I would like to delete its swap area also. But I am not able to find which is the swap area of kali(because both the swap areas are identical). SO is there any way to find which swap area belongs to which so that I can delete kali's swap.

Comment: Look in fstab. Often when I install a second install it includes all swaps, so have several and typically then delete all but one. You can see fstab with `cat /etc/fstab`You can see if it is mounted with `mount` You can see lots of details with `'lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,model,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,partuuid`

Comment: Unless you are using system hibernation, SWAP areas are not system specific (but they do have a specific format ala `makeswap`). Just choose one to keep, make sure Ubuntu is using it and not the other, then delete the other.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu check the swap UUID in your `/etc/fstab`, Use `blkid |grep swap` to get the UUID and the device name of the two swap partitions. If the Ubuntu swap is identified, the other one can be deleted.